# Getting java.net.URISyntaxExceptiin: Illegal character error when we pass space in url for GET method

Tags: api, karate, web-api-testing, getmethod

‘’’

```
Get url baseurl + ‘/api/Search 1’

When method GET

Then print response
```

‘’’

Throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path` for this. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path

Try this following test and see it work:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path 'api', 'Search 1'
* method get
```

Actual request:

```
1 > GET https://httpbin.org/anything/api/Search%201
1 > Host: httpbin.org
```